# Implementing JavaScript function areDifferent(oldValue, newValue) to compare emptiness human-like style

Tags: javascript, angularjs, compare, coercion

I'm getting and object from the back-end with some properties and use AngularJS to put them into input fields (inputs, textareas, checkboxes, dropdown lists).

These properties are in some cases a text value, in some a number value but can also be `null`, `undefined`, `false` or `""`.

I clone this object and then check if user is making any modifications to each of these values by comparing the old (stored) value with new (current) one.

I don't want to use the `ng-dirty` class for detecting a change because it does not disappear when you go back to the previous value after a prior modification (e.g. when using Ctrl+Z).

I thought this task would be simple however I'm getting trouble with this due to [ambiguous nature of JS](http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) values.

Of course I treat every of these:

- `null`
- `undefined`
- `false`
- `""`

an "empty value" because for user "an empty field is an empty field", regardless of what the model stores underneath. So, for example, a change from `undefined` to `""` is not really a change.

So far I've got this:

```
$scope.areDifferent = function (oldValue, newValue) {

    var a = true, b = true;

    if (oldValue === null ||
       oldValue === undefined ||
       oldValue === false ||
       oldValue === "") {
        a = false; 
    }

    if (newValue === null ||
       newValue === undefined ||
       newValue === false ||
       newValue === "") {
        b = false; 
    }

    if (!a && !b) {
        return false; // both values are "empty"
    }
    else if (a != b) {
        return true; // one of the values is "non-empty"
    }
    else {
        return oldValue != newValue; // compare the value of "non-empty" properties
    }
}
```

But I'm curious if this is correct (are there any non-covered edge cases?) and if it can be simplified, because I know that in JS there are some useful [shorthand coding techniques](https://www.sitepoint.com/shorthand-javascript-techniques/) like:

- `a || ''`
- `if(a)`
- `if(a.length)`
- `if(a == null)`

I've tried to use them here but it only leads to frustration because there is always an edge case which is not covered. Any help appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that you want to treat `false` as an empty value? and what about `0` and `NaN`? are they a thing?

Comment: in text input `'0'` is truthy.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, because when property arrives as `null` or `undefined` and the user switches it on and then off again, the new value will be `false` and for the user it's still the "original" value of checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [exclusive OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) and check the values with

```
if (!oldValue && newValue || oldValue && !newValue) {
    // update
}
```

that means, if either `oldValue` is truthy and `newValue` is falsy or `oldValue` is falsy and `newValue` is truthy then make an update of the data.

An extended check for same type and changes.

```
if (!oldValue && newValue || oldValue && !newValue || typeof oldValue === typeof newValue && oldValue !== newValue) {
    // update
}
```

Comment: Looks like your answer is correct but I only needed to add `ng-false-value="'false'" ng-true-value="'true'"` for AngularJS in my HTML because looks like a `false` value arrives to model as `"false"`. Oh and please fix the typo in the last variable name (I guess it should be `newValue` not `value`). Apart from that it's great.